# Asp Core 2.0 HTTP Error 502.3 Bad Gateway

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, bad-gateway

Yesterday, last time when i run my project there is no error, but now i run it, i have error

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway 
>   The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>    terminated the process.

i am not **changing any code** in my project yet. i **already debug** it, and all `local data` is returning correctly. **but it still bad gateway**.

Anyone know what is this issue?

**Edited**

After i restart my pc, i have no error anymore. But still, i confuse about it. Is that because my pc performance? Or anything goes wrong with IIS?

Comment: After restart, my problem solved too!

Answer (score 1):

Download VS installer, press "Modify" and add press checkbox near "Development time IIS support"
[image]